# I need to make date field in dd/mm field

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to make below field in dd/mm format so when user write any number it will automatically convert into in this format like we enter like Expiry date when we do payment. I am trying to do using WordPress contact form 7 plugin

```html
<input type="number" id="birthday" name="birthday" class="birthday" placeholder="your birthday DDMM" inputmode="numeric">
```

can I get this or any idea how I can do that.

Comment: It makes not much sense to input a date with just the day and month but without year. You could alternatively use a normal text input and format it to your liking.

Comment: Make sure you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This makes answering your question a lot easier.

Comment: After looking at the source file of the question, I want to inform you that you need backticks (`) before and after your code. Otherwise, it tries to render the HTML as a part of the post.